# indexing and searching textfiles in ruby and sinatra

Tags: ruby, indexing, full-text-search, sinatra, wiki

I'm making a wiki with Ruby and Sinatra and need to search the wiki's that are stored as text files with markup in a few HTML-renderers (redcarpet, markdown, creole, slim, haml..).
You have a lot of options in Ruby like ferret, solr or lucene gems that handle structured data in a database but not for searching files with free text.

For now I open the text files and search with a regExp but as the wiki's grow that will soon be too slow. Are there any gems that index all the text files in a map and which index I can then use to search the files? It needs to be a Ruby only solution or something that can be easily used from Ruby.

I'm not using one of the common wiki's since none has the features I need.

I do use windows indexing service in a few old ASP apps but I'm far from satisfied with that solution.

My OS'es are Windows Vista, 7 and Windows Server 8.

EDIT: a no database installation needed/no keep server running solution is preferable, so eg with sqlite or file besed storage or something like that

Comment: Well, what kinds of things do you want to search for?

Comment: just strings like with google but don't need much features, speed and simplicity are more important

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll see what I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would choose ElasticSearch: http://www.elasticsearch.org/

It's very easy to get running, and there are some gems for which make it really easy to communicate with it from Ruby ( for instance tire)

I'm not aware of any performant text-file-based full-search engines, so I'd really think that you would be best of by looking for a simple server, which ElasticSearch provides imho.

Comment: seems interesting, easy install, lots of options but degrades nicely, i'm testing it out

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ThinkingSphinx`, a ruby bridge between `Sphinx` and `ActiveRecord`. Using this gem will allow you to index your models in an easy way, and to perform simple searchs and full text searches on all the models of your application.
Home page and documentation of the project:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/
Nice little intro of how to use it:
http://www.synbioz.com/blog/2012/05/18/full_text_search_with_sphinx
I believe that the integration with `Sinatra` would be seamless if work with `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: i see that MySql is required (or a few others), but they all need installation and a server running, i would prefer a no installation/no server needed solution with eg sqlite or file based storage

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Solr with both SQL and Mongo databases in Rails 2.3 - 3.2 and it has been doing great for me so far. Take a look at [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=asciicast). Solr is a full text search java client develpoed by Apache that can index microsoft documents, text file, rich text documents
 and even do OCR on images.

Comment: can you give a simple runable example without using rails (i use sinatra) and if a database is necessary, with sqlite ?

Comment: @peter Sunspot (http://sunspot.github.com/) is compatible with any ruby class (whether its an activerecord model or something else). Please read sunspot github page and their examples. They do it for both rails and non-rails use case. You can use sqlite if you want. Their wiki page has good examples also for setting up your development and production envs.

Comment: can't find a simple example which indexes a file and searches it without lots of dependencies, can you point me to one ?